# Pointer Varible within Structure , of same structure type

Tags: c++, c

What exactly happens when a pointer variable is declared of struct 'node' type within that struct   'node'?

```
struct node 
{
   int x;
   node *next;
};
```

Code used for creating Nodes in Linked List..

Pls Explain it in Detail.... Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It may help your understanding to know that all data pointers are the same size.

Comment: This code is not valid C.

Comment: @KerrekSB its used in linked list implementation in c

Comment: [Try to compile it](http://ideone.com/2LAC0k) before making claims like this. If even *minimal* effort seems too much, please don't post on this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing special happens.

The name `struct node` is valid for use right at the opening `{`, and the compiler knows everything it needs to know in order to support a member of type `node *` at that point.

Of course there's nothing actually recursive in terms of memory usage here, since the member is just a pointer.

Comment: why is that pointer made of type struct 'node' rather than using a integer pointer? or is     node *next;   indirectly a integer pointer with respect to x?

Comment: @BHUPATHYAP Because it points to a node and not an integer. A node and integer are different sizes and support different operations.

Comment: @BHUPATHYAP beacause pointer will point to the next structure and not to any integer.Remember the next element should also have a pointer to the next element, so the next element is not just an int, but a structure.

Answer (score 1):

Link between the nodes in the list is saved by this pointer.
It is just like you have a set of students who has his own details as well as the address of another student.
You can start from the student in the front of the row and go meeting them by reading the address each one holds.
Similarly, in this case struct holds the address of the next node in the pointer.

Comment: why is that pointer made of type struct 'node' rather than using a integer pointer? or is node *next; indirectly a integer pointer with respect to x?

Comment: Each pointer should have know the type of data it is pointing to. You can get some idea reading this http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ .